# Cmake include path for system and program files

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to configure cmake, that it's possible to make a difference if headerfiles are included with `#include<...>` or `#include "..."`?

Lets assume that I have a project like this:

```
src
   foo.h
   foo.c
lib
   foo.h
   foo.c
```

How can be achieved to add the file `src/foo.h` by writting `#include "foo.h"` and if the headerfile is included with `#include <foo.h>` the file at location `lib/foo.h` is loaded?

It always load the files from the first `include_directories()` command

```
include_directories(src)
include_directories(lib)
```

### EDIT

My current problem inside my project:
I have a file named `string.h`. Which contains some function for custom text handling. Now I have the problem that if I write `#include <string.h>` my custom file is loaded, but I expect the system file s`tring.h`. I don't want to rename my custom file nor I want to move it inside a folder to include it like `#include "custum/string.h"`

All I want is:

```
#include <string.h> // load file from system library
#include "string.h" // load my custom file
```

I used it inside IDE Keil like this ways, but I don't know if it can be done with cmake

Comment: Doubt you can, as they use the same search path

Comment: Be sure to very carefully read the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77092/577603) and [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266/577603) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename). After that, you are hopefully convinced that what you are trying to do here is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change include order

```
include_directories(lib)
include_directories(src)
```

You will need to place your whole code in the `src`. In this case `#include "foo.h"` starts search files in the same directory where current file is parsed. `#include <foo.h>"` starts search in include directories in the order of `include_directories`.

BTW it is a bad practice to do such things. Your files should be searched first and then lib files. Better way is to do like

```
include_directories(src)
include_directories(parent_of_lib)
```

Use `#include "foo.h"` or `#include <foo.h>` for your own included files and `#include <lib/foo.h>` for third-party included files.

Comment: Thank you very much fro the reply. I update my question with a currently use case. I don't want to rename/move my files!!!

Comment: You have created a problem for yourself from scratch. Try to think how do you solve this problem using the compiler in the command line, is it possible to solve it?